# How to set correctly styles in css for all child class?

Tags: html, css

I havening problems with css code. I need set a background color in div class .user_avatar and .user_name, they some childs of **.user .user_header**.

I declare in css styles this: **.user .user_header .user_avatar, .user_name { ..**
Is this correctly? or this: **.user .user_header .user_avatar, .user .user_header .user_name { ..**

```css
.user .user_header .user_avatar, .user_name {
  background: white;
  }
```

```html
<div class="user">

  <div class="user_header">
  
    <div class="user_avatar">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_name">
      <h3>User</h3>
    </div>
 
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: You can use this `.user .user_header div`

Comment: if there were another div? for example, **<div class="user_email"></div>** and I want not set css class for this div? only for .user_avatar and .user_name

Comment: .user .user_header .user_avatar, .user .user_header .user_name correct

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying it :)

Answer (score 1):

With this approach you will be facing specificity issues. You can have a read through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Ideally you want to keep control of your styles by maintaining a 10 points specificity (targeting classes, not using cascading selectors).

In your problem, the correct way would be

```
.user_avatar, .user_name {
    background-color: white;
}
```

But as you can see there is a redundancy. Here your classes are describing the roles of your divs, while you could define it differently, with a more broader role in the UI.

```
<div class="user">

  <div class="user_header">

    <div class="user__info">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    </div>

    <div class="user__info">
      <h3>User</h3>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

In the above code, I arbitrarily changed the child classes to `user__info`, following BEM convention (http://getbem.com/naming/).

That way, now you can have only one class to deal with your background color (or any other applicable style to your child classes).

```
.user__info {
    background-color: white;
}
```

For further reading on the subject, I would recommend you'd have a look at this article: https://csswizardry.com/2015/08/bemit-taking-the-bem-naming-convention-a-step-further/
as well as this one which is an evolution of the previous article: https://www.xfive.co/blog/itcss-scalable-maintainable-css-architecture/

This is also a more general interesting take on scalable CSS: http://mrmrs.io/writing/2016/03/24/scalable-css/

Answer (score 0):

The following is not correct:

```
.user .user_header .user_avatar,
.user_name {
```

You have to repeat the ancestors like this:

```
.user .user_header .user_avatar,
.user .user_header .user_name {
```

However, you could probably skip the `.user` at the top and only target the header, or directly use the class names of your elements:

```css
.user {
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 200px;
}
.user_avatar, .user_name {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="user">

  <div class="user_header">
  
    <div class="user_avatar">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">
    </div>
    
    <div class="user_name">
      <h3>User</h3>
    </div>
 
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

div's background is transparent by default so you can do it simple like that:

```
.user_header {background: white;}
```

if you want to have all div childs of user_header the same you can:

```
.user_header > div {background: white;}
```

Since you already got classes for children you can do it like that:

```
.user_avatar, .user_name {background: white;}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

you can do that in different ways:

**using descendant combinator:**

```
.user .user_header .user_avatar, .user .user_header .user_name {
   background: white;
}
```

**or using child combinator**

```
.user > .user_header > .user_avatar, .user > .user_header > .user_name {
   background: white;
}
```

However, I recommend you follow http://getbem.com/ convention for cleaner css files.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct but the second one is more specific.